# Python: if arrived to end of list

Tags: python, list

**Here's the program I wrote for my assignment:**

```
def codes(lst, cods):
    lst1=[]
    for element in lst:
        cccc = element[0:4]
        yyyy = element[4:8]
        mm = element[8:10]
        dd = element[10:12]
        if cccc in cods:
            lst1 += [cccc, int(dd), int(mm), int(yyyy)]

        if cccc not in cods:
            lst1 += [cccc + yyyy + mm + dd]
    return lst1

first = ['Cara20130716', 'Tara20080601', 'PALA19961231', 'Melo19601023']
secnd = ['PALA', 'CARA', 'Tara']
print codes(first, secnd)
```

[**try it at repl.it**](http://repl.it/1Fo/1)

The only problem is, actually the teacher wants me to add/remove elements to lst: the code I wrote gives me *exactly* the right output, but it should 'return' lst, not lst1.
So here's the solution I was thinking about (sorry for the pseudo-code..):

> if cccc in cods:
>                   lst1 += [cccc, int(dd), int(mm), int(yyyy)]
>
> if cccc not in cods:
>                   lst1 += [cccc + yyyy + mm + dd]
>
> if arrived to end of lst:
>                 replace lst with lst1
>
> return lst

So when the program has checked out all elements of lst, it would do something like

```
lst[:] = []
lst.extend.lst1
```

Is that possible? How can I do it?

Comment: What was the original question in the assignment?

Comment: I'm not sure if `lst.extend.lst1` will work at all. `extend` is a method, it should get some list elements. It could work like `lst.extend(lst1)`. And also you can use `extend` instead += in your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do a copy of `lst` in first place, then append the new elements to the original list? Maybe I don't quite get what you're trying to achieve:

```
def codes(lst, cods):
    lst1=lst[:]
    lst[:] = []

    for element in lst1:
        cccc = element[0:4]
        yyyy = element[4:8]
        mm = element[8:10]
        dd = element[10:12]

        if cccc in cods:
            lst += [cccc, int(dd), int(mm), int(yyyy)]
        else:
            lst += [cccc + yyyy + mm + dd]

    return lst

first = ['Cara20130716', 'Tara20080601', 'PALA19961231', 'Melo19601023']
secnd = ['PALA', 'CARA', 'Tara']
print codes(first, secnd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-



def codes(lst, cods):
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        cccc = lst[i][0:4]
        if cccc in cods:
            yyyy = lst[i][4:8]
            mm = lst[i][8:10]
            dd = lst[i][10:12]
            lst.pop(i)
            lst.insert(i, cccc)
            lst.insert(i+1, int(dd))
            lst.insert(i+2, int(mm))
            lst.insert(i+3, int(yyyy))
            i += 3
        i += 1
    return lst
first = ['Cara20130716', 'Tara20080601', 'PALA19961231', 'Melo19601023']
secnd = ['PALA', 'CARA', 'Tara']
print codes(first, secnd)
```

If it helps, don't forget to accept it as an answer! :)